# Nodo en C guarda "basura" en lista simplemente enlazada

Tags: c, lista, nodos

Tengo un problema con un codigo en C.

Tengo una lista simplemente enlanzada que corresponde a la carga de articulos. Entonces cada nodo tendria; un codigo de articulo, una cantidad y un precio.

la condicion de corte de la carga, es decir cuando la carga termina, es cuando el codigo de articulo sea igual a 0, entonces el nodo siguiente es igual a NULL (h->sig = NULL).

A su vez el programa separa en otro nodo los articulos cuya cantidad sea mayor a 500.

El problema reside en la carga de los elementos, y no lo estoy pudiendo identificar, ya que a la hora de ingresar 0 en codArt para terminar la carga de datos, no solo guarda el 0 sino que tambien rellena con "basura" los demas datos (cantidad y precio).

lo que intente hacer fue modificar la funcion "mostrar" de tal forma que ignore el 0, pero eventualmente me di cuenta que no solucionaba el problema debido a que si yo quisiera insertar un nodo al final de la lista no lo mostraria.

Aqui el codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct numeros
{
    int codArt;

    int cantidad;

    int precio;

    struct numeros *sig;

}lista;


void crear (lista *h)
{
    printf("ingrese el codigo del articulo: ");
    scanf("%i",&h->codArt);

    if (h->codArt==0)
    {
        h->sig=NULL;

    }
    else
    {

        printf("ingrese cantidad: ");
        scanf("%i",&h->cantidad);

        while (h ->cantidad <= 0)
        {
            printf("La cantidad cannot be 0 m8: ");
            scanf("%i",&h->cantidad);

        }

        printf("ingrese precio unitario: ");
        scanf("%i",&h->precio);

        while (h->precio <= 0)
        {
            printf("El precio cannot be 0 m8: ");
            scanf("%i",&h->precio);
        }

        h->sig=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));
        crear(h->sig,cont);
    }


}


void pasar(lista *h,lista *pm)//paso los valores hacia otro puntero.
{

    if(h != NULL)
    {
        if(h->cantidad > 500)
        {
            pm ->codArt = h->codArt;

            pm ->cantidad = h->cantidad;

            pm ->precio = h->precio;

            pm->sig=(lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));

            pasar(h->sig, pm->sig);
        }
        else
        {
            pasar(h->sig,pm);

        }

    }
}






void mostrar(lista *h)
{
    while(h != NULL)
    {
        printf("codArt: %i\t",h->codArt);
        printf("cantidad: %i\t",h->cantidad);
        printf("precio: %i",h->precio);
        printf("\n");
        h = h->sig;
    }
}








int main()
{


    lista *pm = NULL;

    lista *p = NULL;

    p = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));

    pm = (lista*)malloc(sizeof(lista));

    crear(p);

    mostrar(p);

    printf("\n");

    pasar(p,pm);

    mostrar(pm);



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

el output es el siguiente:

```
ingrese el codigo del articulo: 2131
ingrese cantidad: 321
ingrese precio unitario: 32
ingrese el codigo del articulo: 12
ingrese cantidad: 543
ingrese precio unitario: 21
ingrese el codigo del articulo: 0
codArt: 2131    cantidad: 321   precio: 32
codArt: 12      cantidad: 543   precio: 21
codArt: 0       cantidad: 12648640      precio: 1550606697

codArt: 12      cantidad: 543   precio: 21
codArt: 0       cantidad: 12648640      precio: 1550606697
codArt: 12652144        cantidad: 12648640      precio: 0
```

Comment: La "basura" ya está ahi antes de que el objeto haya sido siquiera creado. `malloc()` te devuelve la dirección de memoria en la que puedes guardar tus datos, pero no garantiza que esa zona esté "limpia". En general el contenido será cualquier cosa que estuviera ahi antes (pues la memoria se "recicla"). Si quieres asegurarte de que se inicializa con ceros, usa `calloc()`.

Comment: Comprendo, de todas formas me piden que utilice malloc() para resolver este problema. Por otro lado probe utilizar calloc() y me da un problema similiar.

Comment: Si usas `malloc()` asegúrate entonces de inicializar tú mismo todos los campos, dándoles el valor por defecto que consideres apropiado, por ejemplo cero.